# One glossary for different files

Tags: glossaries, multiple-files

I'm trying to do a symbols list for different files. I have two files file1.tex and file2.tex, I want to have a symbols list containing the symbols of both files, but I don't know how to write it correctly in order to obtain the references to the different files.
I have a symbols.tex with the symbols from both files in the format:

```
\newglossaryentry{id}{
.
.
.
}
```

and the output for a symbol s1 in file1.tex should be

```
s1 description, page reference (in file1.pdf)
```

and for file2.pdf I want to achieve something like

```
s1 description, 1-page reference (the number 1 being a symbol to be aware that this symbol occurs in file1)
```

to reference equations, figures, etc. between files I'm using `xr` package and latexmkrc as suggested in [ShareLaTeX](https://es.sharelatex.com/learn/Kb/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_ShareLaTeX), but I cannot figure out how to do something similar with glossaries (I'm very new with glossaries).

Comment: Do you mean something like the [sample-suppl-main-hyp.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/samples/sample-suppl-main-hyp.pdf), which includes a cross-reference to another document? (In this case, the cross-reference is a section number, but it can be the page number.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes is exactly like that!, can you post it as an answer because a comment cannot be marked as an answer. Code would be appreciated, because I still have some doubts with the `\theHsection` and the `\theHvalue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `glossaries-extra` extension package, but it's quite limited unless you use `bib2gls`. At least version 1.14 of `glossaries-extra` is required, although the latest version is best.

I'll start with the standard makeindex method. In this case only the internal references are automated. The cross-references are done manually, which is sub-optimal.

Here's the first document called `test-supp.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample 1},
 description={first example}}

\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample 2},
 description={second example}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample}
\gls{sample1} and \gls{sample2}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The build process is:

```
pdflatex test-supp
makeglossaries test-supp
pdflatex test-supp
```

The glossary contains two entries indexed on page 2:

[image: Glossary sample 1 first example 2 sample 2 second example 2]

The second document is called `test.tex` and contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\glssetcategoryattribute{supplementary}{externallocation}{test-supp.pdf}

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{category={supplementary},
 name={sample 1},
 description={first example}}

\newglossaryentry{sample3}{name={sample 3},
 description={third example}}

\begin{document}
\section{Sample}
In this document: \gls{sample1} and \gls{sample3}.
(Test link to check the PDF viewer:
\hyperref{test-supp.pdf}{}{page.2}{2}.)

\printglossaries
% manually index other document:
\glsadd[format=glsxtrsupphypernumber,thevalue=2]{sample1}
\end{document}
```

This requires knowing that `sample1` was indexed on page 2 of the cross-referenced document. The document build process is:

```
pdflatex test
makeglossaries test
pdflatex test
```

[image: image of second document]

The external links are in cyan as that's the default colour with `hyperref`'s `colorlinks` option.

A more automated method can be achieved with `bib2gls`. The entries are now defined in the file `sample-entries.bib`, which contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@entry{sample1,
  name = {sample 1},
  description = {first example}
}

@entry{sample2,
  name = {sample 2},
  description = {second example}
}

@entry{sample3,
  name = {sample 3},
  description = {third example}
}
```

The `test-supp.tex` file needs to be modified to:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record % requires bib2gls
 ]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={sample-entries}% entries defined in sample-entries.bib
]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample}
\gls{sample1} and \gls{sample2}.

\printunsrtglossaries %<-- changed
\end{document}
```

The document build process is now:

```
pdflatex test-supp
bib2gls test-supp
pdflatex test-supp
```

The result is the same as before.

The second document `test.tex` needs to be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record % using bib2gls
]{glossaries-extra}

% separator between locations in this document and in the other
% document:
\newcommand{\bibglssupplementalsep}{; }

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src=sample-entries,% data in sample-entries.bib
 supplemental-locations=test-supp,% records in test-supp.aux
% set the category label for entries that have supplemental
% locations:
 supplemental-category={supplemental}
]

\begin{document}
\section{Sample}
In this document: \gls{sample1} and \gls{sample3}.
(Test link to check the PDF viewer:
\hyperref{test-supp.pdf}{}{page.2}{2}.)

\printunsrtglossaries % <-- changed
\end{document}
```

The build process is now:

```
pdflatex test
bib2gls test
pdflatex test
```

The result is nearly the same as before except that the external location has been separated from the internal one with a semi-colon.

[image: 1 Sample In this document: sample 1 and sample 3. (Test link to check the PDF viewer: 2.) Glossary sample 1 first example 1; 2 sample 3 third example 1]

You can change the selection criteria so that it includes all the entries defined in the source bib file that were indexed in the cross-referenced file with `supplemental-selection={all}`:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src=sample-entries,% data in sample-entries.bib
 supplemental-locations=test-supp,% records in test-supp.aux
% set the category label for entries that have supplemental
% locations:
 supplemental-category={supplemental},
% Add all entries in the supplemental file that have been
% defined in sample-entries.bib:
 supplemental-selection={all}
]
```

Or you can have a comma-separated list of entries that have been indexed in the other document. For example:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src=sample-entries,% data in sample-entries.bib
 supplemental-locations=test-supp,% records in test-supp.aux
% set the category label for entries that have supplemental
% locations:
 supplemental-category={supplemental},
 supplemental-selection={sample2}
]
```

### Further Customization

The supplemental location list is encapsulated with `\bibglssupplemental{`*n*`}{`*locations*`}` where *n* is the number of locations and *locations* is the code to format the location list. In the above example, this is:

```
\bibglssupplemental{1}{\setentrycounter[]{page}\glsxtrsupphypernumber{2}}
```

There's only one location, so the first argument is 1. Each location first identifies the counter (in this case `page`) to allow the correct formation of the hyperlink reference. The default definition is provided in the `.glstex` file created by `bib2gls`:

```
\providecommand{\bibglssupplemental}[2]{#2}
```

which ignores the first argument.

The actual location is encapsulated with `\glsxtrsupphypernumber{`*location*`}`. This is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\glsxtrsupphypernumber}[1]{%
 {%
   \glshasattribute{\glscurrententrylabel}{externallocation}%
   {%
     \def\glsxtrsupplocationurl{%
       \glsgetattribute{\glscurrententrylabel}{externallocation}}%
   }%
   {%
     \def\glsxtrsupplocationurl{}%
   }%
   \glshypernumber{#1}%
 }%
}
```

This first checks if the entry's category has the `externallocation` attribute set. If it does, then it defines `\glsxtrsupplocationurl` to that value, which makes `\glshypernumber` an external link. Otherwise `\glsxtrsupplocationurl` is set to empty, in which case `\glshypernumber` is just a normal internal link.

So it's possible to make some adjustments to the way the supplementary locations are displayed. For example, to add a prefix to the entire list:

```
\newcommand{\bibglssupplemental}[2]{%
  supplementary
  \ifnum#1=1
   reference:
  \else
   references:
  \fi
  #2%
}
```

(This needs to go before `\GlsXtrLoadResources` so that the `\providecommand` in the `.glstex` file does nothing.)

To prefix each supplementary location:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrsupphypernumber}[1]{%
 {%
   \glshasattribute{\glscurrententrylabel}{externallocation}%
   {%
     \def\glsxtrsupplocationurl{%
       \glsgetattribute{\glscurrententrylabel}{externallocation}}%
     [file: \glsxtrsupplocationurl]
   }%
   {%
     \def\glsxtrsupplocationurl{}%
   }%
   \glshypernumber{#1}%
 }%
}
```

(This needs `\renewcommand` as it's defined by `glossaries-extra.sty` not in the `.glstex` file.) These two modifications produce:

[image: sample 1 first example 1; supplementary reference: [file: test-supp.pdf] 2]

If the supplementary locations are concatenated into a range (for example, 2--4) then the location list will be in the form:

```
\bibglssupplemental{3}{\setentrycounter[]{page}\glsxtrsupphypernumber{2}\delimR \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsxtrsupphypernumber{4}}
```

The range delimiter `\delimR` is the same as for ordinary internal locations (`--`) and is outside of the encapsulator, so the above modification to `\glsxtrsupphypernumber` will alter both the start and end of the range:

[image: sample 1 first example 1; supplementary references: [file: test-supp.pdf] 2–[file: test-supp.pdf] 4]

Comment: just one more thing about this (I don't know if I have to post another question or a comment is enough) I already change my glossaries files to use bib2gls, which I believe is great, but I would like to do something with the page references of the glossaries, in your example prints: **sample 1** first example 1; 2. But some times can happened something like **blah** foo 1; 1, which I believe is not nice. Is possible to achieve something like **sample 1** first example 1; I-2? My first attempt was `\newcommand{\bibglssupplementalsep}{; I-}`but I actually have 3 files so this is not good enough

Comment: @LuisTurcio I've updated my answer. It will be more complicated if there are multiple external files, so you may need to post a follow-up question for that.

Comment: sorry for this, but I'm not sure if you saw the [follow up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445678/customization-of-glossaries) question and I can't figure out how to do the customization. For your comment "It will be more complicated if there are multiple external files" I can say that I'm not smart enough to achieve what I want